# Issue with Retina and ccTouchBegan in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have been working in xCode on a game in cocos2D and have one problem to resolve which seems beyond my grasp.

Essentially I am using SneakyButton which is a custom class that captures touch events so you can use a PNG file or Circle Radius to do something. In my case fire bullets.

When I run the project on the device in SD mode (1x scale) for iOS (For pre iPhone 4 retina) displays all runs fine.

However when I run the project in in Retina display mode (2x scale) on the device... I set the scale to 2X in the delegate for the app. The PNG can be seen. All works fine except the touches are not showing up.

I have narrowed it down to this part of the code.

```
'
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (active) return NO;

    CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];
    location = [self convertToNodeSpace:location];
        //Do a fast rect check before doing a circle hit check:
    if(location.x < -radius || location.x > radius || location.y < -radius || location.y > radius){
        return NO;
    }else{
        float dSq = location.x*location.x + location.y*location.y;
        if(radiusSq > dSq){
            active = YES;
            if (!isHoldable && !isToggleable){
                value = 1;
                [self schedule: @selector(limiter:) interval:rateLimit];
            }
            if (isHoldable) value = 1;
            if (isToggleable) value = !value;
            return YES;
        }
    }
return NO;
}
'
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!active) return;

    CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView:[touch view]]];
    location = [self convertToNodeSpace:location];
        //Do a fast rect check before doing a circle hit check:
    if(location.x < -radius || location.x > radius || location.y < -radius || location.y > radius){
        return;
    }else{
        float dSq = location.x*location.x + location.y*location.y;
        if(radiusSq > dSq){
            if (isHoldable) value = 1;
        }
        else {
            if (isHoldable) value = 0; active = NO;
        }
    }
}
'
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!active) return;
    if (isHoldable) value = 0;
    if (isHoldable||isToggleable) active = NO;
}

- (void)ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self ccTouchEnded:touch withEvent:event];
}

@end
'
```

I think my problem is in the radius part of the code... Has anyone ran into this before or do you have any ideas of what part of this code I need to mod to make it work? It's my last stumbling block before completion of this 6 month project! help! Thanks in advance too!

Answer (score 0):

where are you setting the radius? or how do you get it? if ur getting radius from the png file itself make sure your using the boundingbox for radius rather then contentsize which gives the radius of the sprite before any scaling is applied.